# How to test ios version without bubblewrap

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I'd like to open maps on ios6 by usine `MKMapItem` but I'd also like fallback using google maps for older ios versions...

I have no Idea to do this on rubymtion without BubbleWrap cause `Device.ios_version` return me an error

I want to this this on iOS6 :

```
address_dictionnary = ({kABPersonAddressStreetKey: @party.place.street, kABPersonAddressCityKey: @party.place.city,kABPersonAddressZIPKey: @party.place.postal_code})
place = MKPlacemark.alloc.initWithCoordinate(@coords, addressDictionary: address_dictionnary)
mapItem = MKMapItem.alloc.initWithPlacemark(place)
mapItem.name = "#{@party.name}"
options = ({
   MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
})
mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
```

And this on older versions :

```
url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=#{@party.place.location[1]},#{@party.place.location[0]}&daddr=#{@party.place.location[1]},#{@party.place.location[0]}"
App::open_url(url)
```

Thanks for your help

---

And then when I do the correct test :
When I do the test and I run it on IOS 5.1 I have this error

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
```

This is my code :

```
if Utils.older_than_ios6?
  url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=#{@party.place.location[1]},#{@party.place.location[0]}&daddr=#{@party.place.location[1]},#{@party.place.location[0]}"
  App::open_url(url)
else
  address_dictionnary = ({kABPersonAddressStreetKey: @party.place.street, kABPersonAddressCityKey: @party.place.city,kABPersonAddressZIPKey: @party.place.postal_code})
  place = MKPlacemark.alloc.initWithCoordinate(@coords, addressDictionary: address_dictionnary)
  mapItem = MKMapItem.alloc.initWithPlacemark(place)
  mapItem.name = "#{@party.name}"
  options = ({
     MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey: MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving
  })
  mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By checking the source for `Device.ios_version`, you can see that it returns `UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion`. So this should do the trick !

Comment: You should create another question.